# Elementary proof of growth estimate for a polynomial via size from its zero set

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

The paper *Asymptotic properties of polynomials and algebraic functions of several variables* by Gorin contains the following.

**Lemma 3.1.** Let $f\in \mathbb R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Suppose $f$ has a root in the interior of the unit circle. Then there exists a positive constant $c$ such that $$\|f(x)\|\geq c \cdot d(x,f^{-1}(0))^{\deg f},$$ where $d$ denotes the standard metric on $\mathbb R^n$.

The proof involves a previous theorem which is itself rather involved.

**Question.** Is there a quick direct proof of the above lemma?

Comment: The statement is weird. The stated bound on $\|f(x)\|$ is invariant under shifts, hence the condition on a root in the unit circle should be redundant – you can always shift the polynomial so that e.g. the origin is a root. If $f$ has any root at all, that is.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I agree the condition is redundant, but it's part of the statement in the reference, so I figured I should write it down.

Comment: Sure. I just mentioned it because it raises the possibility that there is a typo in the original paper.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I guess the evaluation point is supposed to be in the disk (or some other compact) too. The statement is clearly false in the entire space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Russian original text](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/6d10d251a8c07ce8e60bf7f30ddd3e1d/rm6566.pdf) clearly states that the exponent is not $\deg f$ but just *some* $\alpha>0$. For $\alpha=\deg f$ is it not true: a polynomial $f(x,y)=x^{2n}+(x-y^n)^2$ has a unique zero $(0,0)$, but $f(\delta^n,\delta)=\delta^{2n^2}$.

I remember obtaining a cubic  *upper* bound for $\alpha$ in the case of a polynomial in two variables with a single zero (but the estimate holds only in a disk centred at the root, not on the whole plane). I may try to find it if you wish.